# Logging, How to get command end?

Tags: c++, templates, logging, stl, std

So I use such [Log class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674060/customize-cout/674120#674120):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class Log
{
public:
    int i;
    Log()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    template <class T>
    Log &operator<<(const T &v)
    {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << ":"  << v << ";" <<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Log &operator<<(std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&)) 
    {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << ":"  << *f << ";" <<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Log()
    {
        std::cout << " [end of message]" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Which I use like:

```
#include <log.h>

int main()
{
    Log a;
    a << "here's a message" << std::endl;
    a << "here's one with a number: " << 5;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

I want my log class to get when I put ";" meaning if I have `a << "here's a message" << std::endl;` I want it to be capable to get that it is oune log message and `a << "here's one with a number: " << 5;` is another.

crently it outputs next message:

```
1:here's a message;
2:
;
3:here's one with a number: ;
4:5;
```

I want to keep its sintax (unlimited number of `<<`, big range of value types, no `(` and `)` around in api) but make it output:

```
1:here's a message
;
2:here's one with a number: 5;
```

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `operator<<` return a temporary value which will place `endl` upon destruction and forwards all `operator<<` calls to the main object. This way, `endl` is guaranteed to be called exactly once.

```
class Log
{
struct EndlOnDeath {
    Log* log;
    EndlOnDeath(Log* ptr)
        : log(ptr) {}
    template<typename T> EndlOnDeath& operator<<(const T& val) {
        (*log) << val;
    }
    ~EndlOnDeath() {
        (*log) << std::endl;
    }
};

public:
    int i;
    Log()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    template <class T>
    EndlOnDeath operator<<(const T &v)
    {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << ":"  << v << ";";
        return this;
    }
    Log &operator<<(std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&)) 
    {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << ":"  << *f << ";" <<std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Log()
    {
        std::cout << " [end of message]" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Deterministic destruction is Teh Epix WinRAR™

Comment: @DeadMG: main point was to make it possible to divide not `one text line` messages but `one code line messages` so for example `a << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;` would be one message.

Comment: Idea is fun but it just does not compile=( I get C2143 or C2914 and C2676

Comment: Well after many banch tests we came with approach much similar to yours (but threadsafe) [here.h](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-util/log_util.h?r=1443) and [here.cpp](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-util/log_util.cpp?r=1443)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a special object which, when inserted, indicates the end of the log entry. I know this is not exactly what you want, but it's really easy to implement. It also leaves you the flexibility to spread a log entry over several statements (which is useful for generating parts of a log entry within a loop, for example).

```
struct LogEnd {};
const LogEnd logend;

class Log
{
public:
    Log() : number_(0) {}

    template <typename T> Log& operator<<(const T& x)
    {
        ss_ << x;
    }

    Log& operator<<(const LogEnd& aLogEnd)
    {
        // Dump the stringstream string to output with desired decorations.
        std::cout << number_ << ": " << ss_.str() << std::endl;

        // Clear the stringstream
        ss_.str("");

        ++number_;
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream ss_;
    int number_;

};

int main()
{
    Log log;
    log << "This is " << 1 << " log entry" << logend;
}
```

Comment: How is this any different to just `endl` directly?

Comment: I think the OP wants each log message to have a number prefix. It's not just a matter of appending a newline at the end of each log message. Edited answer with numbered log message functionality.